# Data not set in excel

Tags: excel

i have a piece of code to right into excel sheet,it is based on the row number and column name specified ,my issue is that if a column name is null then value will not set in the rest of the columns.[image]

in this excel no value get added after Column 'D'

Below is my code

```
public boolean setExcelData(String sheetName, String colName, int rowNum, String data) throws AutoException {
    dataFile();
    try {
        if (rowNum <= 0)
            throw new AutoException(EXCEPTIION);

        int index = wb.getSheetIndex(sheetName);
        int colNum = -1;
        if (index == -1)
            throw new AutoException(EXCEPTIION);

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(index);
        Row row = sheet.getRow(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
            System.out.println(row.getCell(i));
            if (row.getCell(i) == null) {
                throw new AutoException(EXCEPTIION);
            } else if (row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName)) {
                colNum = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (colNum == -1)
            throw new AutoException(EXCEPTIION);

        sheet.autoSizeColumn(colNum);
        row = sheet.getRow(rowNum - 1);
        if (row == null)
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum - 1);
        Cell cell = row.getCell(colNum);
        if (cell == null)
            cell = row.createCell(colNum);
        cell.setCellValue(data);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(excelFilePath);
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            wb.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Any one can help me out.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

skip the for loop iteration if columnname is null

```
for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
    System.out.println(row.getCell(i));
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(colName))
        continue;
    if (row.getCell(i) == null) {
        throw new AutoException(EXCEPTIION);
    } else if (row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue().trim().equals(colName)) {
        colNum = i;
        break;
    }
}
```